# Rudin 5.23(convergence of recursive sequence)

Tags: real-analysis

Really having a tough time proving this

> Let $\alpha,\beta$ be fixed points of the $f(x)=\frac{x^3+1}{3}$ where $-2<\alpha<-1$ and $0<\beta<1$. Show that if $\alpha<x_1<\beta$ then $x_{i+1}=f(x_i)$ converges to $\beta$ as $i\to \infty.$

I have been tackling this problem and managed to prove a couple facts in general about this problem.

- $x<y\implies f(x)<f(y)$
- $\alpha<x_i<\beta\implies \alpha<x_{i+1}<\beta$
- $x<f(x)$ for $x\in (\alpha,\beta)$

  Which is fairly close to the solution, but doesn't tell me that $\beta$ is the lub of $\{x_i\}$.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know $(x_n)$ is increasing, so it either tends to $\infty$, or it converges. You know $\alpha < x_n < \beta$, so it does not tend to $\infty$, hence it converges. But if $x_n$ converges, take the limit of the equation $x_{n+1}= f(x_n)$ to get $x_\infty = f(x_\infty)$ since $f$ is continuous. Thus $x_\infty$ is either $\alpha$ or $\beta$, and hence must be $\beta$ because the sequence was increasing.

Comment: Why must it necessarily "stop" at the fixed points. Couldn't there be a point $x\in (\alpha,\beta)$ such that $x_i<x$ for all i. For example $x_i=1-\frac{1}{i}$ it follows that $0<x_i<2$ but $\lim\limits_{i\to \infty}x_i\neq 2$.

Comment: It is true because it is true, I proved it. Take the limit of the equation $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$. Since $f$ is continuous (left continuous would be enough since $x_n$ is increasing) you get $x_\infty = f(x_\infty)$. Thus $x_{\infty}$ is a fixed point of $f$.

Comment: Oh, hmm well that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

$\alpha < x_1 < \beta \implies f(\alpha) < f(x_1) < f(\beta) \implies \alpha < x_2 < \beta \implies ... \implies x_n \in (\alpha, \beta), \ \forall n \ge 1$

Next:

$x_1 < f(x_1) = x_2 < f(x_2) = x_3 < ... < x_n$

If $x_n \to \alpha$, then it must have been decreasing.

Therefore...